# Submit Form Without Saving to List

Tags: workflow, delete, item

How could one create a form which does not actually save form data to the list upon submission? The data will be used in a workflow which fires a powershell command using a workflow action solution by [iLoveSharepoint](https://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com). No need to save data to the list; list data will be fetched from Active Directory using a 3rd party plugin.

One possibility I thought of is to use the action "Delete Item in [Current Item]" at the end of my Workflow. I haven't tested this yet, but presumably it should accomplish what I want. I wonder, is there a more elegant option available?

Answer (score 0):

Workflows have to fire on the creation or edit of something or manually. So in your case, the submission would create a temporary list item, then delete itself after it's done if you no longer need it.

It might behoove you to not delete it incase there are errors on the Powershell side, you could come back and manually trigger the workflow again.

Edit:
It looks like those are targeted at 2007 and 2010, I don't know if they integrate with site workflows, but perhaps a site workflow could be created to do what you want. These are not tied to lists or libraries so there wouldn't be a list item to worry about, you just set some initiation parameters usually and it does what it does.